# Angular phonegap app navigation issue

Tags: angularjs, cordova

This is a phonegap + angularjs project. Let say i am on this page

```
     file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/groupHome"
```

Now i got a notification and i am changing hash as below on clicking notification:

```
window.location.hash= "/groupHome?groupId=xyz";
```

If am on any page except `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/groupHome"` navigation happening correctly but if i am on `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/groupHome"` page its not navigating

```
$stateProvider
        .state('groupHome', {
            url: "/groupHome",
            templateUrl: "groupHome.html"

        })
```

Here is redirection

```
if(window.location.hash.indexOf("/groupHome")>-1)
{

   angular.element("[ng-controller =groupHomeController]").injector().invoke(['$state',function($state) {
                        $state.reload("/groupHome?groupId="+msg.extraParam.groupId);
                    }]);

            }
            else
                window.location.hash="/"+msg.extraParam._nextPage+"?groupId="+msg.extraParam.groupId;
```

Comment: Is your problem only present on phone gap or also in a normal web browser ?

Comment: i am testing it on android mobile

Comment: In phone gap our default browser ? What about laptop ?

Comment: this is android app developed using phonegap so i am testing on simulator as wel as on android phone

Comment: Can you give us your route definition for this view please.

Comment: have a look i updated

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

for navigation from one view to other views smoothly